# Change text color of a portion of navigation drawer item

Tags: android-studio, navigation-drawer, textcolor

In Android Studio, I want to change the color of a portion of a item in the Navigation Drawer. In the image attached [Navigation Drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWIwy.png), I want the word "PRO" to appear red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a spannable string:

```
MenuItem item = (MenuItem) navigation.getMenu().findItem(R.id.miItem);
String str = item.getTitle().toString();
SpannableString span = new SpannableString(str);
span.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), str.length() - 3, str.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
item.setTitle(span);
```

replace 
`navigation` with your `NavigationView` variable  
`miItem`  with the corresponding `MenuItem`'s id

Comment: So, the only way to do that is in java code? In xml is not possible?

Comment: @DarilAlemán Maybe if you resolve to html tags but I have not ever used it.